# I am Trying to generate a random array(property) via a class in php

Tags: php

Please could someone help me make this work? i am trying to use a class to generate a random list of activities from an array i have as a Property in the class.

```
<?php 
   class Activities{
      //single array Property
      //16 activities to print 5 random ones

      public $activity = array('Surfing','Day Spa','WIFI','Diving','Snorkeling',
      'Island Tours','Cable Ski','Mountain Bike Trails','Bar',
      'Fishing','Yoga','Shooting','Spear Fishing','Pool','Hiking Trails',
      'Quiz Nights');  

      //method
      public function randAct($activity){
      echo $this->$activity ;
      }
      $rand_Keys = array_rand($activity,5);
         echo $activity[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
         echo $activity[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
         echo $activity[$rand_keys[2]] . "\n";
         echo $activity[$rand_keys[3]] . "\n";
         echo $activity[$rand_keys[4]] . "\n";
         echo $activity[$rand_keys[5]] . "\n";
   }
?>
```

how do i do this?
the output i am looking for is for example: Surfing Yoga Pool Bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this for example:

```
class Activities{
    //single array Property
    //16 activities to print 5 random ones

    public $activity = array('Surfing','Day Spa','WIFI','Diving','Snorkeling',
      'Island Tours','Cable Ski','Mountain Bike Trails','Bar',
      'Fishing','Yoga','Shooting','Spear Fishing','Pool','Hiking Trails',
      'Quiz Nights');  

    //method
    public function randomActivity(){
        echo $this->activity[array_rand($this->activity)];
    }
}

$a = new Activities();
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $a->randomActivity();
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thank You! now all i need to do is stop it from repeating itself :)